# Другая альтернатива — грамотно ли так говорить?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Помню, как-то в школе я написала что-то вроде "У нас нет другой альтернативы".
Меня поправили: так говорить нельзя.
Действительно ли нельзя сказать "другая альтернатива"? Ведь альтернатив этих, по идее, может быть несколько.

Answer (score 2):

Значение слова *альтернатива* расширилось.  Это не только выбор между несколькими возможностями, но и сами эти возможности. Заметьте при этом, что  альтернатив может быть больше двух.  Анализ примеров показывает, что сочетания «2, 3 и больше альтернатив» допустимы, хотя, как утверждает Gramota.ru,  и не вполне закрепились в русском языке. В этом случае *альтернатива* – синоним *альтернативного варианта*. А вот сочетание *другая альтернатива* зачастую оказывается избыточным.

Нужно анализировать контекст и, если можно сформулировать короче, значит, «другая альтернатива» – плеоназм.

*Предлагаю 2 альтернативы: одна такая, другая такая.* Здесь многословие, т. к. можно сказать: *Предлагаю альтернативу: это или это.*

*Предлагаю 3 альтернативы: одна такая, другая такая, третья такая.* Такой вариант допустим.

*«Можно сделать это или это». – «А другая альтернатива есть?»* Здесь неточное словоупотребление: 3-й вариант – не другой, а еще один. Правильнее: *А еще одна (или 3-я) альтернатива есть?*

*Могу предложить только две альтернативы, третьей не нахожу.* Вариант допустим.

*Из двух альтернатив я выбираю вторую.* Допустимо.

Анализируем примеры с форума:

***Альтернатива – дрова. Нет, дорого... Ищем другую. Другая альтернатива – уголь.***
Если дрова не альтернатива, то уголь – не другая «не альтернатива», а таки альтернатива: *Альтернатива – дрова. Нет, дорого... Дрова не альтернатива. А что же альтернатива? Уголь.*

***Мост был разрушен, пришлось идти вброд – другой альтернативы этому мосту у нас не было.*** Такой вариант возможен. Акцентируются две альтернативы (вторая при этом не существует) по отношению к третьей. Брод – единственная альтернатива мосту, другой нет.
Ср.:  *Мост был разрушен, пришлось идти вброд – альтернативы не было.* Множество сокращается до двух: нет альтернативы броду.

То есть *другая альтернатива*  – это *вторая альтернатива*. И это значение актуально, когда речь идет о множестве больше трех или когда два варианта пронумерованы и нужно точно определиться с номером. Когда же имеется в виду просто другое, не такое, как это, это просто альтернатива, поскольку она уже включает в себя 2 варианта.

Comment: >Дрова не альтернатива.   
  
Да почему?! Дрова именно что альтернатива газу. Одна из двух или более. А если не альтернатива, зачем о вообще них вспомнили? А если бы оказалось, что уголь еще дороже? Пример-то совершенно условный.  
  
Кстати, пример вообще мало чем отличается от истории с мостом. Только там другой альтернативы" не было, а тут она есть. Вот и вся разница.

Comment: Я говорю о внимании к контексту. В вашем контексте дрова не альтернатива (ну ваши же слова!). А после слова "нет", то есть "не альтернатива", возможно только "а это альтернатива", а не "другая". Логика-с. Другой пример - другой и разговор. Например: Дрова - одна альтернатива газу, уголь - другая. Или: Дрова - более приемлемая альтернатива газу, чем уголь.

Comment: Хотя если понять "нет" как "нет, эта альтернатива не подходит", можно поискать и другую.

Comment: >В вашем контексте дрова не альтернатива (ну ваши же слова!).   
  
Я такого не говорил.    
Дрова - альтернатива. Первая. Но не лучшая.   
Не знаю, при чем тут контекст.

Answer (score 1):

Вас правильно поправили. Альтернатива - это и есть одно или другое, от латинского alter - другой . Альтернатива всегда предполагает выбор между взаимоисключающими: или А,или Б,или В.Т.е ситуация, в которой надлежит произвести выбор одной из двух исключающих друг друга возможностей, что не предполагает понятие " другой" . В данном случае "другая альтернатива" -плеоназм.

Answer (score 1):

Я не совсем согласен с поправившим.
Мне тоже несколько резало слух еще лет тридцать назад, но увы...
В современном языке альтернатива - это не только выбор из двух (иногда - и более) вариантов, но и каждый такой вариант сам по себе.

Так что надо смотреть контекст. 
Если используется в значении "альтернативы [тому-то] нет", то да, "другая альтернатива" - плеоназм, ничем не оправданный.

Но если под этим понимается все-таки не выбор, а каждая из опций... Почему нет?! 
*Мост был разрушен, пришлось идти вброд - другой альтернативы этому мосту [как то: лодки, вплавь] у нас не было.*

Плюс ко всему, нельзя исключать и нечто подобное использование: "У нас есть альтернатива (быть или не быть) - и другой альтернативы (пить или не пить) нет". К этому-то уж никак не придраться.

Answer (score 1):

Процитирую в качестве ответа доктора филологических наук Н.С. Валгину.

> Таким образом, в значении слова "альтернатива" уже есть сема "другой"
>   (один из двух). Однако новые контексты (прямо скажем, неудачные,
>   искажающие смысл) десемантизируют прямое значение слова, в частности,
>   в сочетании очень распространенном в современной прессе — «другая
>   альтернатива». Такое употребление нельзя признать нормативным, пока
>   владеющие нормативным языком ощущают ошибочность подобных сочетаний,
>   однако сам путь к изменению значения уже намечен.

Answer (score 0):

Слово "альтернатива" (фр. alternative, от лат. alternatus — другой) имеет два значения:

а)Необходимость выбора одной из двух или более исключающих друг друга возможностей: Передо мной встала альтернатива - расшифровать информацию или быть с позором изгнанным.

б) Каждая из этих возможностей: Ищем альтернативу для газового отопления. Какая альтернатива скайпу?

Ошибка возникает при втором значении слова. В этом случае альтернатива - это другой вариант, и у нас получается "другая альтернатива" - это другой "другой вариант".

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ-УТОЧНЕНИЕ

Непонятно, о чем такой длинный разговор - казалось бы, вполне приемлемое решение для слова "альтернатива" в обоих значениях уже СУЩЕСТВУЕТ.

1. У нас есть альтернатива – возможность выбора (1-ое значение слова)

А, В, С – это альтернативы (альтернативные решения) (2-ое значение слова).

Мы выбираем  А или (В, С),  при этом В и С – альтернативы для А.

В и С - ПРОСТО АЛЬТЕРНАТИВЫ: не первые, вторые, третьи и не другие.

1. У нас нет альтернативы – нет возможности выбора (берем, что дают).

http://www.bulatokudgava.ru/speak/9_11_00.htm

Comment: Вот не понял, почему именно при втором ошибка?!
Я бы сказал, что скорее при первом.

Comment: Есть вариант - разводить кур, и есть альтернатива (другой вариант) - разводить уток.

Comment: Это Вы мне на вопрос ответили?
Ответа не понял, по-прежнему считаю, что Вы принципиально ошиблись.  
Именно при том понимании, которое у Вас "второе", возможно использование другая альтернатива. 
>Ищем альтернативу для газового отопления.   
  
Ищем. Альтернатива - дрова. Нет, дорого... Ищем другую. Другая альтернатива - уголь. А, это пойдет.  

А вот как объяснит возможность "другой альтернативы" для "первого" Вашего значения - что-то не соображу. Разве что по принципу: одна альтернатива "быть или не быть", другая - "пить или не пить". Вы об этом?

Answer (score 0):

Альтернатива — это другая возможность (решения, выбора, действия, реализации желания, достижения поставленной цели), другой вариант выбора возможного решения, который определяется относительно одного из рассматриваемых вариантов, возможностей решения поставленной задачи, цели, реализации намерения, выражения мысли, передачи информации, донесения понимания...
Альтернатива проявляется в сравнении с каким-то из имеющихся вариантов для выбора,  относительно определённого условия или возможности для выбора, то есть альтернативой всегда будет другой вариант выбора, который определяется относительно одного из возможных вариантов и имеет в сравнении с ним некие отличия, другие условия. Альтернатива — это другая возможность решения, как минимум одна из двух, ибо единственная возможность — это отсутствие альтернативы. Ситуация, в которой не находят другой возможности для необходимого решения, называется безальтернативной.

Когда есть необходимость попасть на другой берег реки, а моста нет, выбор перейти реку вброд становится альтернативой относительно условной возможности перехода по мосту, привычного решения, на что рассчитывали люди, имеющие необходимость перейти реку. Только переход вброд не является другой альтернативой в этой ситуации, так же, как и единственной альтернативой. Моста нет, нет возможности для перехода по мосту, а принятая позиция людей в том, что у них нет другой альтернативы для перехода на другой берег, не оставила им выбора, кроме решения идти вброд!
Это отсутствие какой-либо альтернативы, безальтернативный выбор, вынужденное решение, которое удобно называть альтернативой, чтобы создать иллюзию выбора, удобная версия для самообмана. Альтернативой переходу реки вброд будет вариант перебраться вплавь. ДРУГОЙ альтернативой может быть собранный плот, платная переправа, аренда лодки, вертолёта, строительство моста... Другой, то есть более одной возможности попасть на противоположный берег реки, относительно выбранной возможности перейти вброд.

Когда выбор решения определяется как единственный, он не может быть никакой альтернативой, это безальтернативный выбор.