# Лучшая альтернатива

Tags: грамотная-речь

"ЕГЭ несовершенен, но лучшей альтернативы ему нет». Является ли употребление «лучшая альтернатива» ошибкой в данном случае?

Comment: Если придираться, тут логическая ошибка. Но так говорят и звучит нормально, потому что не стоит требовать от языка математической строгости. Правильно так:
"ЕГЭ несовершенен, но лучше альтернативы ему нет»
или
"ЕГЭ несовершенен, но лучшая альтернатива ему не лучше ЕГЭ»

Comment: Меня поправляют, указывая вариант "Нет лучшей альтернативы ЕГЭ, чем гибкая организация системы конкурсного отбора абитуриентов", а тот, что вопросе - как ошибочный. К сожалению, я не вижу большой разницы в этих двух предложениях.

Comment: Ну союз "чем" используется только со сравнительной степенью прилагательного. С превосходной он не может использоваться. "Альтернатива лучше, чем что-то" - корректно. "Альтернатива лучшая, чем что-то"/"Альтернатива более лучшая, чем что-то" - некорректно. Но тут еще вопрос в нормах речи. Как принято говорить, так и правильно. Да и союз "чем" , может, может использоваться в других конструкциях, надо про него почитать поподробнее. Например: "Я другой, чем он." считается корректным, хотя режет слух.

Answer (score 3):

*ЕГЭ несовершенен, но лучшей альтернативы ему нет*. **Это неправильно?**

*Нет лучшей альтернативы ЕГЭ, чем гибкая организация системы конкурсного отбора абитуриентов*. **Только так правильно?**

Попробуем ответить на эти вопросы.

Как в современном языке понимается ***альтернатива***?

1. Нам нужно **обязательно что-то выбрать** – ЕГЭ или другой вид контроля знаний, без этого обойтись нельзя.  Перед нами ряд возможных решений (разные альтернативы),  но выбрать мы должны **только одно** решение.  Именно такая ситуация связана с понятием ***альтернатива***.
2. Мы  не готовы выбрать что-то иное, чем ЕГЭ, **все варианты кажутся неподходящими.** Тогда мы говорим:  (1) *ЕГЭ несовершенен, но лучшей альтернативы ему нет*.
3. Но есть другое мнение: **есть лучшая альтернатива** – это гибкая организация системы конкурсного отбора абитуриентов. Тогда мы говорим: *Нет лучшей альтернативы ЕГЭ, чем гибкая организация системы конкурсного отбора абитуриентов*.  Это **оценка существующих вариантов**, то есть из всего ряда альтернативных предложений мы готовы выбрать именно это. Но это совсем **другая мысль.**
4. Вывод. Оба  речевых варианта  **верные**, но они имеют **разный смысл**.

**Примечание.** Такое толкование альтернативы соответствует современному словарю, но вот раньше, как мне думается, **альтернативного ряда** (нескольких возможностей) вообще не было: один (исходный) вариант противопоставлялся другому (единственному). Выбор же  нужно сделать обязательно и выбрать можно только одно решение (поэтому говорится о взаимоисключающих возможностях).

[https://kartaslov.ru/какой-бывает/альтернатива](https://kartaslov.ru/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B1%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82/%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0)

Большой толковый словарь

**АЛЬТЕРНАТИВА** [тэ], -ы; ж. [франц. alternative]. 1. Необходимость выбора между **двумя или несколькими исключающими друг друга возможностями**. 2. Каждая из этих возможностей. Иметь альтернативу.

Управление в русском языке

**АЛЬТЕРНАТИВА** чему. Не существует альтернативы политической разрядке.

Comment: Спасибо за поддержку.

Comment: Думаю, что и раньше было *так же* :), Просто "альтернативу" называли "заменой". _Несовершенен ЕГЭ, но лучшей замены ему не найти. Нет лучшей замены ЕГЭ, чем гибкая организация..._

Comment: Alex_ander, в чем-то я согласна  с вашим комментарием, и пример ваш мне нравится, но определенные замечания есть (я их выкажу позже). Тема не так уж проста, на форуме она уже обсуждалась.   Я прочитала тот материал еще до ответа, но не стала сразу приводить ссылку – хотелось исключить влияние ранее выказанных мнений. Надеюсь, что другие участник выскажут свою точку зрения тоже, ведь времени с момента того обсуждения прошло уже немало. https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/32277/Другая-альтернатива-грамотно-ли-так-говорить

Answer (score 1):

На мой взгляд, тут логическая ошибка.

**Альтернатива — это что-то доступное, как другая возможность.**

Например: *«Альтернативой бегу является аэробика»*.

Если на улице зима, и я не могу бегать на улице, я могу заняться аэробикой.

Бегу могут быть другие альтернативы, например, скакалка, бассейн.

Но лучшей альтернативой бегу в зимний период является аэробика. Она лучшая среди альтернатив, а не по сравнению с бегом.

Можно сказать: *«В зимний период лучшей альтернативой бегу является аэробика»* (по сравнению со скакалкой и бассейном).

Но нельзя сказать: *«Лучшей альтернативы бегу нет»*.

Это бы значило, что:

- либо все альтернативы бегу (аэробика, скакалка, бассейн) равнозначны, и никакая из ни не лучше;
- либо, что альтернатив вообще нет.

Это как, в классе нет лучшего ученика. Или все учатся абсолютно одинаково, или учеников вообще в классе нет, и выбирать не з кого. Оба варианта мало правдоподобны.

Правильней было бы сказать: *«Бегу нет альтернативы»*.

---

Я считаю, неправильно: *«ЕГЭ несовершенен, но лучшей альтернативы ему нет»*.

Правильно: *«ЕГЭ несовершенен, но альтернативы ему нет»* (нет другой доступной возможности).

---

И ещё, может, кто-то не согласится, но всё же:

**Лучший — это превосходная степень: хороший, лучше, лучший.**

Строго говоря:
Когда мы сравниваем две вещи, одна может быть лучше, другая хуже. Если вещей больше двух, тогда можно говорить о лучшей, например, среди трёх.

Поэтому использование степени сравнения «лучшей» в оригинальном предложении вообще звучит странно.

Думаю, если хочется использовать степень сравнения, можно ещё сказать:
*«ЕГЭ несовершенен, но лучше его ничего нет»*.

Comment: Да, все правильно. И как вишенка на этом торте выглядит статистика из нацкорпуса: лучше чем/лучшая(ий) чем = 5882/25. Еще интересно такое словосочетание: "Ещё лучший" = 26